# Manager for all Organic Groups

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I am working in a project that requires the use of organic groups and I was wondering is there is a way to setup a "global" drupal role that will give the users with that role access to all groups as managers.

Note: This managers might not be the user that created the group.

Comment: Is there anything speaking against just making them site admins? Or making all the groups subgroups of one big group and granting the global group managers permissions in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extending the answer from [Essam Al-Qaie](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/44357/essam-al-qaie) on [og_role_override](https://www.drupal.org/project/og_role_override)

implementing a custom permission in a new module will help to separate this from the rest of your site.

```
function mymodule_permission() {
  return array(
    'global og manager' => array(
      'title' => t('Global OG manager'),
      'description' => t('Be a manager for all og groups, globally.'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I received the same request once .. and what I need is this module [og_role_override](https://www.drupal.org/project/og_role_override)

> This module provides Core permissions to act as particular OG roles in
>   specific group types.
>
> In other words, it creates permissions of the form 'Act as ROLE in
>   GROUP-TYPE' for each role and each OG group type. Granting this
>   permission to a Core role gives it the same permissions as that OG
>   role, in all groups of that type.
>
> For example, you might want users with your 'site editor' role to be
>   able to act as a 'board member' in all OG groups, without having to
>   add them to each group, and without having to replicate all the OG
>   permissions as Core permissions.

Hope it helps ..